# Cone unfolding of space curves

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

There is a natural length-preserving operation which transforms any rectifiable space curve $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to R^n$ into a planar curve $\tilde\gamma \colon [a,b]\to R^2$. This operation, which has been called *(cone) unfolding*, was used in a [paper of Cantarella, Kusner and Sullivan](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-002-0234-y) to study thickness of knots, and more recently in a [paper  with James Wenk](http://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Eghomi/Papers/sphere.pdf) to prove [Zalgaller's sphere inspection conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69099/shortest-closed-curve-to-inspect-a-sphere/375199#375199) for closed curves.

I would like to know when this operation may have been first used, and what other applications of it might be known.

The cone unfolding is defined as follows. Let $o$ be a point in $R^n$ not lying on $\gamma$. Consider the conical surface $C$ generated by all the line segments $o\gamma(t)$. The unfolding $\tilde\gamma$ of $\gamma$ with respect to $o$ is the curve obtained by the isometric immersion (or unrolling) of the conical surface $C$ into the plane $R^2$. Note that unfolding preserves the arc length between any pairs of points of $\gamma$, and does not decrease the chord length. In particular, if $\gamma$ is polygonal then $\tilde\gamma$ will be polygonal as well.

[image]

If $\gamma$ is closed, i.e., $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ then we may choose the point $o$ so that $\tilde\gamma$ will also be closed. To see this let $\overline\gamma(t):=(\gamma(t)-o)/|\gamma(t)-o|$ be the projection of $\gamma$ into the unit sphere centered at $o$. The total length of $\overline\gamma$ may be called the *vision angle* $\theta$ of $\gamma$ with respect to $o$. If $o$ lies in the convex hull of $\gamma$, then it follows from Crofton's formula that $\theta\geq 2\pi$. On the other hand $\theta$ may be arbitrarily small if $o$ is chosen far from the convex hull of $\gamma$. So, by continuity, we may choose $o$ so that $\theta=2\pi$. Then $\tilde\gamma$ will close up as desired.

Comment: From the top of my head, I think it was used by Choe in one of his papers on the isoperimetric inequality on minimal surfaces (he notably proves that a minimal surface with at most two boundary components satisfies the Euclidean isoperimetric inequality, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks Benoit. I see cone constructions over curves in some papers of Choe, and even reference to "visions angle" in a paper with Gulliver, but I do not see that they unroll the cone into the plane.

Comment: You might be right, sorry.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I guess this unrolling method proves the Almgren isoperimetric inequality in dimension 2: a minimizing surface has area lesser than any cone over its boundary, so one is reduced to the plane inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Liberman used *cylinder unfolding* to study geodesics on convex surfaces.
[Либерман, И. М. «Геодезические линии на выпуклых поверхностях». ДАН СССР. 32.2. (1941), 310—313.]
Right now standard formulation of Liberman's lemma uses cone unfolding (it gives more general statement and proofs are the same).

Latter Alexandrov used *development* of curves that could be considered as a generalization of cone unfolding. [A. D. Alexandrow. “Über eine Verallgemeinerung der Riemannschen Geometrie”. Schr. Forschungsinst. Math. 1 (1957), 33–84.]

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me for this bit of self-promotion, especially because this is
only tangential to the OP's concerns.
But cone unrolling and Anton Petrunin's mention of Alexandrov's developments, in conjunction with the OP's query---"what other applications of it might be known?"---lead to me to mention that in this paper,

> J. O'Rourke and Costin Vîlcu,
> "Conical Existence of Closed Curves on Convex Polyhedra."
> *Computational Geometry*, **47**, pp.149-163 (2014).

we constructed a curve on a cone that overlaps when developed on the
plane. Avoiding overlap would be useful in several contexts,
but alas...

Here is the relevant figure from that paper.

[image: Fig.14]

(a) Open curve on cone of angle $\alpha$, with cone opened.
(b) A different opening of the same cone and curve.
(c) Development of curve self-intersects.