# Covering the unit sphere in $\mathbf{R}^n$ with $2n$ congruent disks

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, sphere-packing

Let $v_i$ be $2n$ points in $\mathbf{R}^n$, with equal distance $|v_i|$ from the origin. Suppose that the convex hull of these points contains the unit ball. Is it known that  $|v_i|\geq\sqrt{n}$? Presumably, the optimal configuration is given by the vertices of a cross polytope, i.e., when $v_i$ are placed on the coordinate axis with $|v_i|=\sqrt{n}$.

[image]

The problem may also be phrased in terms of the smallest radius for $2n$ congruent spherical disks to cover the unit sphere $\mathbf{S}^{n-1}$ (given by points $x\in\mathbf{S}^{n-1}$ with $\langle x, v_i\rangle\geq 1$). So I imagine that either the answer is known, or else this is a well-known problem in sphere covering. References would be appreciated.
The case $n=2$ is obvious, and $n=3$ seems doable. But I am not sure about $n\geq 4$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For $n=3$ the answer is yes, as was shown by [Fejes Tóth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_Fejes_T%C3%B3th) in 1943; see the Theorem on p.34 of his book [Regular Figures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0080100589). For $n=4$ the answer is also positive as shown in the 2000 paper, [The blocking numbers of convex bodies](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1758049), by Dalla, Larman, Mani-Levitska, and Zong. In higher dimensions, the problem appears to be open according to Conjecture 1.3 in the 2003 article, [Covering the sphere by equal spherical balls](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2038476), by Böröczky and Wintsche. In a 2015 paper, [On the Distance of Polytopes with Few Vertices to the Euclidean Ball](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3293493), Tikhomirov showed that $|v_i|\geq C\sqrt{n}$ where $C$ is an absolute constant. Another proof of this fact follows from a result of Nazarov included in the appendix to the 2022 paper [Shortest closed curve to contain a sphere in its convex hull](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.05988), which is discussed in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/430137/68969). Here one may also estimate that $C\geq 0.27$.